# Find the conditional probability that at least one of the numbers is even, given that the sum is 8.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

Problem statement -

We roll two dice. Find the conditional probability that at least one of the numbers is even, given that the sum is 8.

My attempt -

A = {at least one of the numbers is even}

B = {the sum is 8}

Want to find
P(A|B)

P(A|B) = P(A and B)/P(B)

Find P(B). I know that

5+3=8
2+6=8
4+4=8

Are the only possible ways of obtaining a sum of 8. So there are 3 ways of rolling the dice such that the sum is 8. There are two die, so the number of total possibilities is 6*6 = 36. So

P(B) = 3/(6*6) = 3/36 = 1/12

Next, I want to find P(A and B)

There are only two possible ways of having at least one even number and, and the sum being 8 (2+6, and 4+4). So

P(A and B) = 2/36 = 1/18

So P(A|B) = (1/18)/(1/12) = 2/3

This answer seemed right to me, until I checked the back of the book for the answer, and it said 3/5.

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: What you did wrong was counting the number of ways of getting $8$. If you do it your way for all the sums $2$ to $12$, you'll find they don't add up to $36$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following outcomes are equally probable:
$$
(2,6), \quad (3,5) \quad (4,4) \quad (5,3) \quad (6,2)
$$